# How to make a dummy phone call in WINDOW PHONE 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Is there any Library or API by which we can initiate a dummy phone call on windows phone7 Emulator.
i.e When any person calls me during a certain profile the phone should intercept the call and send an sms against the caller.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible on Windows Phone 7 in its current state. Your application wouldn't be capable of running in the background nor can it register for such an event (the platform doesn't auto start apps, the user has to manually start the app via a toast notification or some other direct method).

You also cannot directly send an SMS. You can only [open a pre-populated SMS message](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/deed1aa6-1097-499e-bedc-b2529e5ff6bf), but the user will actually have to hit send and your application will not be running when this is done.